# Can I retrieve the data from a column which contain different kind of data by using BETWEEN?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Data_Insertion

A | MUN170171/P0164 | 16:19:10 | 2018-12-12 
B | MUN170161/P0165 | 17:19:10 | 2018-12-12 
C | MUN170151/P0166 | 18:19:10 | 2018-12-13
D | MUN170141/P0167 | 19:19:10 | 2018-12-13
E | MUN170121/P0168 | 20:19:10 | 2018-12-15
```

The column above contain different kind of data, user, id, time and date. So is it possible to using between to get the range for the time when user selected 1pm to 6pm?

I tried using LIKE but it only able to retrieve one data from the database.

I tried the following but not working:

```
SELECT FROM `table' 
WHERE Data_Insertion >= "13:00:00" and Data_Insertion <= "18:00:00" 
    AND `Data_Insertion` LIKE('%2018-12-12%') 
Group by
```

Is there a way I can make the following work?

Comment: You could get this working using substrings, but a much much better option would be to have different data in different columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of substring to get the value if you think the format of the data will be same as this solution is more like hard coded search rather than flexible one.

```
 Create table  temp5  (Salary int , Data_insertion varchar(250)); 

insert into  temp5 values 
( 1000, 'A | MUN170171/P0164 | 16:19:10 | 2018-12-12')
,( 4000, 'B | MUN170161/P0165 | 17:19:10 | 2018-12-12')
,( 5000, 'C | MUN170151/P0166 | 18:19:10 | 2018-12-13')
,(6000, 'D | MUN170141/P0167 | 19:19:10 | 2018-12-13')
,( 70000, 'E | MUN170121/P0168 | 20:19:10 | 2018-12-15')

select salary, data_insertion, substring(data_insertion, 22, 9) timecomp 
, substring(data_insertion, 33, 11) Datecomp  from Temp5
where cast(substring(data_insertion, 33, 11) as date) = '2018-12-12' and
cast(substring(data_insertion, 22, 9) as time) between '13:00:00' AND '18:00:00'  ;
```

Output:

```
  salary, data_insertion,                               timecomp,  Datecomp
   1000, A | MUN170171/P0164 | 16:19:10 | 2018-12-12,  16:19:10,  2018-12-12
   4000, B | MUN170161/P0165 | 17:19:10 | 2018-12-12,  17:19:10,  2018-12-12
```

I assume there will be some flexible approaches than this if your data format is not consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You want to extract the second-to-last column.  You can do that using `substring_index()`.  So, something like this:

select t.*
from t
where substring_index(substring_index(data_insertion, ' | ', -2), ' | ', -1) between '13:00:00' and '18:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

First, get the data into the right type:

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
MODIFY Data_insertion TIME, MODIFY date_col DATE
```

After that the following will work along with numeric range comparisons (`>` / `<` / `=` ...)

```
SELECT FROM `table' 
WHERE Data_Insertion BETWEEN "13:00:00" AND "18:00:00"
```

Its never a good idea to use string operators, e.g. `LIKE`, on numeric fields.

Comment: Problem is that OP only has 1 column `Data_Insertion` with string value `'A | MUN170171/P0164 | 16:19:10 | 2018-12-12 `'

Comment: ah, eek. I missed that and assumed a typo.